# Can you run an Angular Universal application without a server?

Tags: angular5, angular-universal

There's a feature in Angular Universal that allows you to pre-render pages at build-time. Can this be used to pre-render all your pages and run Angular Universal without a server?

Answer (score 2):

Once html pages have been pre-rendered using angular universal (using nodejs server or asp.net core server), you can use any CDN to serve the pre-generated html.

See https://universal.angular.io/overview/

**Edit**: have a look at the starer kit

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Basically, you can reuse the prerender.js file which will write the rendered html files (for specified static routes) to the dist/browser folder, or wherever you want to. This is that folder that you deploy to a static host after

Comment: You mean just deploy the dist/server folder and any thing like IIS server will be able to serve instead Express?  If so how to do it

Comment: I know it's possible to pre-render the html but I've yet to see it done in a way where you didn't require the web server to respond to requests.

Comment: When your browser asks for a static html file it IS a request, so you'll always need something that responds to requests. I edited my post to add a link to a starter kit

Comment: That "Basically" portion is what I'm looking for. I've never seen it done successfully.

Comment: We're successfully pre-rendering and hosting the generated client applications using Azure static websites. I assume it would also work with AWS S3 static web hosting and similar services. So yes, it is possible to host statically without a Node.js server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're always going to need to have a server somewhere in the equation: the only question is how much you have to set it up yourself versus how much can the current crop of tools and technologies do it for you.

In [this talk from Node Summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qOK5n_zaj4) Steven Fluin from Google talks about **Firebase** at the end. Pay attention to the bit about 'cloud functions' (at about 20 mins). Your Angular app will be rendered on the server using Firebase cloud functions. When a user interacts with your app, some JS is run to figure out what to send down (from the Firebase server) to the user. "You don't need to set up a server at all; everything is running in Firebase."

I haven't used Firebase myself - I'm using Angular Universal, which has a Node.js server as you know - but this sounds very nice. I found setting up Angular Universal really tricky (but got there in the end).